# Zenburn color scheme for Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, color-scheme

I'm looking for the "Zenburn" coloring for Netbeans.

Similar question asked a year ago. All links I find for this are dead.

Topic is still alive but links are dead. http://forums.netbeans.org/topic29869.html

Anyone got something similar / have a working link? Netbeans 7.1.1.

Comment: David, which link are actually dead? The one where you pasted in this question or the link in the forum to download nb.zip? Both are accessible here and I have downloaded nb.zip.

Comment: @Jasonw The pasted link works for me. But the link inside, to nb.zip, does not (404). I tested many times in the last couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I think you click on the 1? Yeah, that will give error 404, have you try click on 2? I've downloaded nb.zip by click 2.

Comment: No worries, sometime we make silly mistake. ;-) learned and then move.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I finally found a [working link](http://niccolofavari.com/dark-low-contrast-color-scheme-for-netbeans-ide).